# How to open Treasure Pods

Tags: slime-rancher

I've placed made and placed over 35 gadgets and I got the thing saying that I unlocked the treasure cracker but it's not in my store or in my blueprints. I can't open the treasure pods either. I've tried restarting my game but it still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A check of the [wiki](https://slimerancher.fandom.com/wiki/Treasure_Pods#) reveals the answer:

> To open Treasure Pods, you must obtain Treasure Crackers from the Vacpack upgrade terminal. There are three tiers, each opening more advanced Pods:
>
> The Treasure Cracker MKI allows you to open Green Pods; it will become available once The Lab is unlocked and your first gadget has been crafted. It costs 4,500Newbucks.
>
> The Treasure Cracker MKII allows you to open Blue Pods and will become available after the MKI Upgrade is bought and a total of 35 Gadgets have been crafted in The Lab. It costs 9,000Newbucks
>
> The Treasure Cracker MKIII allows you to open Purple Pods and becomes available after the MKII Upgrade is bought and a total of 100 Gadgets have been crafted in The Lab. It costs 25,000Newbucks.
>
> It is not necessary to use the gadgets you create to unlock the Treasure Crackers.

Make sure that you have unlocked the Lab in order to gain access to the Treasure Crackers.